# Simple c++ cout statment, one line with a formatting issue, what it is?

Tags: c++, format, echo, cout

Here is my code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()  
{
    ifstream fin;

    fin.open("Celsius.txt");

    if (!fin.good()) throw "I/O error";

    double myC;
    fin >> myC;

    fin.close();   

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("Fahrenheit.txt");
    if (!fout.good()) throw "I/O error";

    double myAnswer = (myC * 1.80) + 32;  
    fixed;  
    cout << myC << " Celsius equals " << setprecision(3) << myAnswer << " Fahrenheit" << endl;  
    fout << myC << " Celsius equals " << setprecision(3) << myAnswer << " Fahrenheit" << endl;  

    fout.close(); 
}
```

Ok, am I just missing some complete fundamental neuron, I seem to have some road block understanding this.

- It's -2 for formatted input echo, and
- It's -2 for not formatting output with one decimal digit.
- Do not format the input values only the output.

  ```
  fixed;
  cout << myInput << " should not be formatted, but " << setprecision(3) << myOutput << " should be" << endl;
  ```

Doesn't that stay:

myInput is the unformatted input echo
and myOutput is formatted to one decimal digit?

Comment: This is nearly incomprehensible. Does the code do what you expect? What is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: Sorry it's a requirement of this program I have to write, I'm just trying to understand the spec.

Comment: tried to clean up your formatting.... not entirely fixed yet.

Comment: Even with the full code posted, it's still not at all clear what you're asking. For example, what are the -2's about? Are they instructions from your homework about how many points will be taken off if you format input/output incorrectly?  Maybe show us the inputs you're using, the output you're getting, and the output you expect.

Comment: Does it make sense to anyone else? I'm taking this class this lady says its 2 points off on this assignment for doing that. I got it graded and the prof said that's what I missed. I asked for further calcification and still don't understand.

Comment: The input is a number to be converted to Fahrenheit, thank you SO MUCH for cleaning up my code! Gosh that was a mess!

Comment: Does that make anymore sense? Could I get a vote up now maybe... please?

Comment: What input did you give it?   What output did you get?  What output were you hoping for?

Comment: One thing I'm still not clear on (and this might be your instructor's fault) is that I'm not sure exactly what's meant by "formatted input echo" (or "unformatted input echo"). Writing to text output always requires some kind of formatting - it's just that the default formatting might or might not be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include fixed in the output stream, like so:

```
cout << myC << " Celsius equals " << fixed << setprecision(3) << myAnswer << " Fahrenheit" << endl;
```

setprecision will specify the number of decimal places after the decimal. So 3 will yeild a number like 72.000, or 1 in your case will set it to 72.0

Comment: Sorry, my output also has to be formatted to 1 digit, maybe I don't understand what setprecision() does exactly? I thought it formatted my number.

Comment: @CodingIsAwesome: try `setprecision(1)`

Comment: It sounds like you're on scientific and not fixed, try ensuring that << fixed << is included before your setprecision.

Comment: I got marked off and my professors previous examples never setprecision() inside a cout, always before. Bummer!